# How to insert UIView on left and indent the cell?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to insert an UIView on the left of a UITableViewCell, but when I do that I don't know how to move/indent the whole cell to avoid overlaying the View.

If I use
`cell.indentationLevel = 10;`
Only the TEXT will be aligned, not the whole cell.

IE: http://i463.photobucket.com/albums/qq357/darkCB666/iOSSimulatorScreenshot19032014000530_zps44572bfa.png

I'm trying to do somehing like WhatsApp and Facebook Chat contact list (the cell lines are aligned with the text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `separatorInset` property instead, like this:

```
cell.seperatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
```

That will inset the line and automatically adjust the default subviews along with it.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

A common trick I've seen and used is to just lay out the cell with my own line to achieve the look I want. Rather than use the iOS default line, insert your own line at the position and length you need to account for the left-hand UIView.